# Is it possible to create web service CRUD operations for contributed modules in drupal 7?

Tags: services

I have using a privatemsg module for chating in our site,

[Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg)

[Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)

Is it possible to do a web service CRUD operations through this module?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Services module has an API, details of which you can find in the module files. You can use that API to provide CRUD for anything at all. See [Creating a resource for Services 3.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/783460) for a full module example.

Since private messages are entities, you might also look to the [Services Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity) module for inspiration (or, it you're particularly lucky, a pre-built solution, depends what you need, and whether you can use an alpha release):

> This module provides support for all Entity API entity types to Services. All entity types get a standard resource, similar to what Services provides for code entity types such as nodes.

Comment: Clive thanks for you're quick reply,i have another module (achievements) is there,how can i perform web services CRUD operations for that module.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that module, sorry. If it uses the entity API you should be able to use the module I linked to, if not it'll probably need something custom written for it (someone may have already started something in a sandbox module, it's worth searching around. "drupal [module-name] services integration" is usually a good search term)

Comment: I have used services entity api,but here having only CRUD operations Retrieve only available,Create,Update,Delete is not available for privatemsg module.

Comment: i have given URL like this ((http://localhost/services/emp/entity_privatemsg_message/2)) for retrieveing for user messages,but it will display error["Access denied for user user"],am i doing any wrong?